# Xournal, cannot draw with pen/highlighter, leaves only a dot

Tags: xournal

When annotating a PDF I select the pen tool or the highlighter tool and want to underline or cross out or highlight parts of the text but after click-hold + drag + release I only get a dot at the position of my initial click as opposed to the line I expect to appear. The dot is the right colour and size, though.

So, the question is: How do I get the pen tool to draw a line?

Versions: Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia (VM on a Win10 host) with Xournal 0.4.8.

(I rarely use Xournal and had to find this answer twice now so I leave my fix here.)

Answer (score 1):

Xournal has a drop-down menu "Options" with the first element "Use XInput" presenting with a checkbox. Uncheck that box to be able to draw lines.